# Wordpress pages permalink rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have WooCommerce installed already and the category url of WooCommerce is like this:

url.com/product-category/category1 works fine for displaying the category.

This is what I am aiming to achieve.
url.com/product-category/category1/pagename

category1 is the name of the category which is set in the page back-end in custom field.

pagename is the name of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can Organizing Your Pages with Parent page

> **To create a subpage**
>
> 1. Go to Administration > Pages > Add New screen.
> 2. In the right menu, click the "Page Parent" drop-down menu. The
>      drop-down menu contains a list of all the Pages already created for
>      your site.
> 3. Select the appropriate parent Page from the drop-down menu to make
>      the current Page a child Page.
> 4. Add content to the subpage.
> 5. Click Publish when ready.
>
> When your Pages are listed, the Child Page will be nested under the
>   Parent Page. The Permalinks of your Pages will also reflect this Page
>   hierarchy.

Comment: It's going to be a subpage of a page. What I want is for it to be a sub page of a WooCommerce category.

Answer (score 0):

I looked for same solution to custom post type and found a lot codesnippet solutions for category functions here.  But i will just recommend rewrites at  manageable permalink like https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-permalinks/. However checking out categories URL codex might be more slim option.